# OSX - Disable External Site Linking for Webview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm working to view a local html page inside a WebView and I want to disable going to any external website if the user clicks any button within the page i.e. `<a href="www.google.com">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a `policyDelegate` for your view. See the docs for `WebPolicyDelegate`. The specific method you want to implement is:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
                                   request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                   frame:(WebFrame *)frame
                                   decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

The simplest thing to do is just call `[listener ignore]` for everything. That will also prevent any back/forward navigation, reloads, or form submits from working. If you want more control, you can look at the `actionInformation` dictionary and check the type before calling `[listener ignore]` or `[listener use]`.

Comment: i have checked the url which is `NSString *url = actionInformation[@"WebActionElementKey"][@"WebElementLinkURL"];` and if it is not nil i called `[listener ignore]`